# To burn the midnight oil

Tags: sentence-meaning, expressions, phrases

Please consider the following scenario:

> - **a)** I'm really jealous of him; he's a really successful engineer. 
>     **b)** Instead, I'm really proud to have such a colleague! You see! He's been a truly diligent person thoughout his whole academic period and now he's enjoying his life! I knew him since many years ago! I remember well; he really **burned the midnight oil** to get where his is now!

Does the bold phrase above mean **to work hard late into the nights for a long time** in modern English? Doesn't is sound old-fashioned to you?

I would appreciate it if you let me know a better idiom in modern language if it's an obsolete type of implying this meaning in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Burning the midnight oil** is still an often-used phrase.

It remains a well understood phrase even though oil lamps are relics of the past.

Just for fun, check your favorite search engine for news articles with this exact phrase.   *Google News* turns up many articles with this phrase in the headline over the past month or so (in 2019).

Answer (score 0):

*Burning the midnight oil* means *to work late into the night*. It implies one is working hard. In the context of the scenario, it means he worked a lot, often late into the night, to get to his present position. It is meant as both a compliment, and a comment on the person's character as a hard-working individual.

*Burning the midnight oil* is still used. There are a few alternatives that are used regularly. *To keep one's nose to the grindstone* would work in that context in the past tense: *He really kept his nose to the grindstone to get where he is now!* Another, more modern, and colloquial, expression is *to pull an all-nighter*, which is mostly used by high school and college students in the context of studying for exams, as in: *I pulled an all-nighter to study for that test!*

However, an *all-nighter* implies procrastination or laziness, waiting until the last moment to prepare. It is uncommon to say *he really pulled a lot of all-nighters to get where he is*, and if used, it would not be a compliment.